# Commands don't have permission when using absolute path

Tags: permissions

I have folders set up this way:

/srv/samba/video

```
getfacl /srv/samba/video

# file: srv/samba/video
# owner: root
# group: nogroup
user::rwx
group::---
group:sambaclients:rwx
group:deluge:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:sambaclients:rwx
default:group:deluge:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

That means, user deluge has rwx to folder /srv/samba/video.

However, when running command as user deluge, I am getting weird permission errors.

When in folder /srv/samba/video:

```
sudo -u deluge mkdir foo
```

works flawlessly.

But when using absolute path:

```
sudo -u deluge mkdir /srv/samba/video/foo
```

I am getting permission denied.

When running `sudo -u deluge id`, I get output

```
uid=113(deluge) gid=124(deluge) skupiny=124(deluge)
```

which shows that user deluge is indeed in group deluge. Also, the behavior was the same when I gave the permissions also to user deluge not just group deluge. When executing as non-system user, it does work.

The reason that I want to use absolute paths is that I am using automatically triggered post-download script which extracts some files into the folder.

I have spent way too many hours to solve this problem myself.
`mkdir` isn't the only command that fails, `touch` is doing the same thing, so I suspect that it's not `mkdir`'s fault.

If you need more info, I will try to put it in here, just ask.
Thanx in advance.

**Edit:**

It seems that the root of the problem is acl set on perent folder `/srv/samba`, which indeed does not grant permissions to deluge (but neither denies it).

```
getfacl /srv/samba
# file: srv/samba
# owner: root
# group: nogroup
user::rwx
group::---
group:sambaclients:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::---
default:group:sambaclients:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

If I grant the permission also to this folder, it suddenly starts to work so I believe that the acl on `/srv/samba` is somehow denying the permissions to deluge.

So the question is: how do I set acl to both `/srv/samba` and `/srv/samba/video` so that sambaclients have access to whole `/srv/samba` and subdirectories and deluge has access only to `/srv/samba/video` and subdirectories?

Comment: Try it with the SGID bit (see chmod command). This bit will give rights to the group and not the user. This might be a bit better to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `deluge` must be able to see contents of the parent directory `/srv/samba`. Thus applying executable bit to it: `chmod o+x /srv/samba` resolved the issue.

The reason why it worked with relative path is that when sudoing the command, we already were in directory `/srv/samba/video` and thus no permission checks were applied.